# Jquery get html content within h1

Tags: jquery, html

I've got this html:

```
<h1>
   <span>
       <span>
          Sony
       </span>
   </span>

   Televisies
</h1>
```

How do I get all content within the `h1` so with the `span html` as as wel?

Comment: `$('h1').html()`. http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: `$("h1").text()`.

Comment: @SalmanA `with the span html as as wel`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan guessing what OP actually wants.

Comment: Why would you think they don't want what they're asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by `html()`. It returns the html content (innerHTML) inside an element

**Code**

```
var h1Content = $('h1').html();
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5k8zv9qj/)**

Comment: Thanks, how do I render this html to normal text back?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a useful function for that: `html()`:

```
var content = $('h1').html();
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I render this html to normal text back?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you want to strip out the html tags from the content?